# Marklogic upgrade - creating local plugin repo

Tags: gradle, marklogic, gradle-plugin, marklogic-dhf

Our servers are not allowed to access internet, and I need to create and use a local repository ( the C:\Plugins directory ) located on the server having its MarkLogic Data Hub v4.1.1 upgraded.

We need to modify the local build.gradle file to use the repository containing the following 2 plugins ( shown in "plugins" section ).

This is current build.gradle file:

```
   plugins {
      // Gradle Properties plugin
      id 'net.saliman.properties' version '1.4.6'

      // Data Hub plugin
      id 'com.marklogic.ml-data-hub' version '4.3.2'
   }


repositories {

if (project.hasProperty("disconnected") && !"FALSE".equalsIgnoreCase(disconnected)) {
       println "using offline repositories"
       mavenLocal()
} else { 
        println"Using online repositories"
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://developer.marklogic.com/maven2/" }
        }
}
```

I have managed to create a local Maven repo and Gradle repo which work well ( using code above in "repositories" section ), but need assistance with these plugins.

If I can get this last part to work, I should have a fully offline hub upgrade process, which will be incredibly useful.

Any help much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quite a few pieces to get it fully working in offline mode:

- local maven repo in `buildscripts` and `repositories`
- a copy of gradlew that has been edited to use a local dir for gradle home, and has its own copy of gradle dist (which kind of beats its purpose, but not entirely)
- and to make plugins work properly, you also need a settings.gradle with `pluginManagement.repositories` pointing to local maven as well

This PR in grove-ml-gradle gives best overview of necessary changes to my opinion: https://github.com/marklogic-community/grove-ml-gradle/pull/2/files

HTH!